# Changing the height of a dynamic-height UITableViewCell after it's already appeared

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.rahttp://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swiftywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift) to create a dynamic height UITableViewCell.

My prototype cell has 1 label (pretty simple).  That label has constraints set to "0" for all sides of the cell edges.  That label has `numberOfLines = 0` and wraps the word.

In my UITableView setup, I do this:

```
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0 //some random number
```

Basically, everything works. Each cell has its own different height.

The problem arises when I update that label with different text.  The height of the cell stays the same, and the text just gets truncated OR white space appears.

Is there a way to tell the cell to "redraw" itself so that it calculates the height again?

Ideally, I'd like to do this **inside** the UITableViewCell class, since that's where it receives a notification to update the label text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implements `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` and calculate your label's size.

for example :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
                        estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath 
                        indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   let model = YourModelArray[indexPath.row]
   // Label fontName and size
   let attributes = [
            NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "FontName-Regular", size: 16) as! AnyObject]
    let nsStringText = model.text as! NSString
    // Calculate the size here 
    //--------------------//
    //--10--UILabel--10--//
    //-----Element------//
    //------------------//
    let size = nsStringText.
                  boundingRectWithSize(CGSize(width: self.tableView.frame.width - 20,
                  height: 1000), 
                  options:[NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin,
                           NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading],
                           attributes: attributes, context: nil)
    // Basically add other elements heights and vertical Spacing between them
    return size.height + element.frame.height + verticalSpacingBetweenLabelAndElement
}
```

Comment: How do I call it though? (When my cell receives a notification center message, it needs to call something to "resize" its own height)

Comment: just implement the menthionned method and call tableView.reloadData()

Comment: Can I reload the cell only and not the entire table?

Comment: yes you should call `tableView. reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation ...)` between `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableView.endUpdates()`

Comment: Why was the accepted answer? This requires code to be added into the UITableViewController class, not the cell itself. It's also a very simple example where there is only text - what if you have a more complex cell?

Comment: `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath ` is a method of the UITableViewDelegate protocol so basically all the code here should be added to a ViewController (`UITableViewController` for example). And i have explained if there is many others components you should add their height and add the verticals spacings between them